# Are we in for Winter Bash 2015?

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange Winter Bash 2015 is coming soon! Are we in??

For those who are new to the Stack Exchange network, Winter Bash is an annual light-hearted event where users can earn virtual "hats" by doing certain things on an SE site within the Winter Bash time frame -- these virtual "hats" that you earn can be "worn" as adornments on your SE avatar either on a particular site (e.g., Coffee) or network-wide (i.e., all of Stack Exchange).

The conditions for earning certain hats are "public" -- well-known to all; other hats are "secret" -- you need to figure out what to do to earn the hat. Some public hats might be... ask a well-received question, improve a question, submit an accepted edit, perform tasks in the review queue, etc. Some non-public hats in the past have been... contribute on a particular day, upvote and comment/improve on a first-question from a new user, etc.

Winter bash can be fun and users will sometimes get hats just by participating normally. Any user can opt-out of the Winter Bash (once it starts, any user can click a link like "no hats for me, thanks"); no hats will be earned nor viewed.

Once Winter Bash 2015 begins (14 December), stats can be viewed at http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/ . Previous years can be viewed at the respective years, or by redirects from previous years -- e.g., http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/ directed to [for 2014](http://stackexchange.com/promos/15/winter-bash-2014) and blog posts like [this one](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/) with more info about secret hats!

An entire site *could* also opt out of Winter Bash. **Are we *in*, Coffee?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### YES!

I'm in. It encourages participation and a general merriment around various holidays and the New Year. It's a fun diversion from oppressively hot and/or cold and/or normal weather, and is simply a *fun time.* Count me in!

Comment: Happy [Winter Bash](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/12/announcing-winter-bash-2015/)! It's [on](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/). :)

Answer (score -5):

### No.

I hate hats. They're pointless and distracting. Every year, I click the "I hate hats" link as soon as it is available and I look forward to it. More coffee... less hats!

Comment: One of the main valid arguments against hats is that they increase the load on moderators as people try to cheat the system in order to get hats. Given the already low moderation burden of this site, I'm happy to have hats.